# Threejs animation issue

Tags: three.js

Trying to load a STL model into a canavas with Threejs is giving me an error every time the animate function is runned;

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'render' of undefined
    at animate (

I know the STL file is good it worked before.

Here is my code;

```
    // Globals 
var scene, camera, light, renderer;

 init();
 animate();


  // Sets up the scene.
  function init() {

 // Create the scene and set the scene size.
scene = new THREE.Scene();

//Scene Lighting
scene.add( new THREE.AmbientLight( 0x000000 ) );

//Renderer
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({canvas: document.getElementById('modelCan'), antialias:true});
renderer.setClearColor(0xfffffff);
renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth/3, window.innerHeight/3 );

//Camera
  var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(1000, window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight, 1, 10000);
  scene.add(camera);
//Camera Lightning
  var light = new THREE.PointLight( 0xffffff, 1);
      camera.add( light );

     var loader = new THREE.STLLoader();
                loader.load( 'Sac_Fuel_Tank.stl', function ( geometry ) {

                    var material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial( { color: 0x286617,
                     wireframe: true 

                 } );

                    var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
                        mesh.rotation.x = Math.PI / 2;
                        mesh.position.set(20,10,-10);
                        //  mesh.rotation.z = Math.PI;
                    scene.add( mesh );


                } );
                controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);

}


  function animate() {

 // Read more about requestAnimationFrame at http://www.paulirish.com/2011/requestanimationframe-for-smart-animating/
 requestAnimationFrame(animate);

 // Render the scene.
 renderer.render(scene, camera);
 controls.update();

}
```

So what am I doinng wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to remove the `var` keyword when creating the renderer. Just do:

```
renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { canvas: document.getElementById('modelCan'), antialias:true } );
```

Comment: Good catch :) I overlooked it. The same about `camera` and `light`.

Comment: As long as you don't use features like `damping` or `autoRotate`, there is no need to update `OrbitControls` in your animation loop.